# Determining the language of a DFA

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I've tried quite a large amount of examples, starting from 1 bit all the way up to 5 bits yet I couldn't put my finger on any recurring pattern of words that are accepted.

the DFA is as such:

[image: the dfa]

The only language I could come up with that sort of covers this, is:

$L=\{w: \#_1(w)\geq 1 \; \& \; ends\;with\;even\;no.\;of\; '0'\;or\;ends\;with\;'1'\}$

yet this formulation for $L$ seems really off to me.

is there a better way to formulate this? or perhaps my answer is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.
$L = \{ w \; | \; w \text{ has at least one 1 and ends with an even number of 0s or ends with a 1 }  \;\}$

Sketch of Proof in one direction: Because there's at least one 1, somewhere we find a 1 and get to $q_2$. To end in $q_2$, either the last word was a 1; or it was zero and last state was $q_3$. Everytime we're in $q_3$, we have an odd number of zeros at the end.

Comment: This is an answer I went through, but the “length” of the definition felt odd to me, though I see the logic behind this definition. I suppose this is the correct answer indeed, thank you!

Comment: Its the same answer the asker suggested.